# How to add support for new HW accelerator into Android system?

Tags: android, opengl-es

My company has developed a 3D HW accelarator and we have EGL + OpenGLES1.1 libraries ready and working under Linux. I need to port those libraries to Android. I also have a working Android on the same hw platform, but it is, of course, using its own sw-based OpenGLES renderer (placed in frameworks/base/opengles/libagl and linked as system/libs/egl/libGLES_android.so).
For start, my idea was to replace the original libagl source by compiling my own library instead, but it is not so simple... I am not sure how to proceed, so here are some questions:

1. Where can I find some docs/specs about this level of Android development?
2. The original SW-based renderer works tightly with dedicated surface provided from the system and any drawing that might occur is done into that surface. I cannot work that way - my HW accelerator always draws into a predefined memory area (having fixed physical address and format), so I need to find a way (2a) to copy the drawing result into the surface provided by the system, or (2b) to tell the system to create a surface pointing to my HW-operated area and format. The 2b would be better because of less copying. What to do and how?
3. My HW accelerator works only with physical addresses. Where and how should I map the known physical address of the output buffer?
4. Is it possible/preferable/useful to use NDK for this kind of development/porting?

Thanks,

Andjelko

Comment: This looks like a platform change. Also [HardwareLayer](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/ics-mr1-release/core/java/android/view/HardwareLayer.java) or [GLES20Layer](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/ics-mr1-release/core/java/android/view/GLES20Layer.java) from Android 3.0 may be a good start point.